# Does Mei's Cyro-Freeze block attacks

Tags: overwatch

Does Mei's `Cyro-Freeze` ability block hitscan or projectiles? If so does it affect both enemy and allies or just one of the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It blocks every single kind of hitscan and projectile weapon, akin to a wall that will take all the damage you deal to it. However, that won't stop weapons like Pharah's Rocket Launcher from dealing splash damage to allies too close to your ice cube, nor will it stop abilities like Concussive Blast from pushing away teammates.

Comment: Just to clarify when you say every single kind I assume you are also inferring allied weapons

Comment: Yep, allied weapons will hit your ice cube, and not go through it.